# Custom Notification with two button

Tags: android, button, notifications

Hi in my project i'm showing notification with two button 1 is for syn and another one is for close. I have used PendingIntent to get the data from the notification but when i click the any button it giving a same value plz help me on this

there is my coding

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void startNotification(){
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, null, 
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.number);

    //the intent that is started when the notification is clicked (works)
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the 
    //button is clicked
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
    switchIntent.putExtra("do_action", "close");
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
            switchIntent, 0);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, 
            pendingSwitchIntent);

    Intent switchIntentsyn = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
    switchIntentsyn.putExtra("do_action", "syn");
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntentsyn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
            switchIntentsyn, 0);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startsyn, 
            pendingSwitchIntentsyn);

    notificationManager.notify(100, notification);
}
```

this is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notifiation_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:contentDescription="Title name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/startsyn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="Syn now" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="close" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this my BroadcastReceiver

```
public static class switchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String action = (String) intent.getExtras().get("do_action");
         Log.i("tag", "action :"+action);
         if (action != null) {
             if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("syn")) {
                 // for example play a music
                 Log.i("tag", "inside syn method");
             } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
                 // close current notification
                 Log.i("tag", "inside close method");
             }
         }


    }
}
```

this is my android manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.testdemo.MainActivity$switchButtonListener" />
```

my out put log is same when ever i click both button

```
 08-27 19:35:01.347: I/tag(8547): action :close
08-27 19:35:01.347: I/tag(8547): inside close method
```

Comment: notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, 
            pendingSwitchIntent); and 
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startsyn, 
            pendingSwitchIntentsyn); you set "notificationView.OnClickPendingIntent" two times, I think that this must be the failure reason.

Comment: @sedpol i've used that only for onclickpendingintent notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startsyn, 
            pendingSwitchIntentsyn);notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, 
            pendingSwitchIntent);

Comment: then how can get onclick for the both button

Comment: Do you really need a "close" button? I think that Android lets the user to close notification via sliding it left to right.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are probably passing the same intent ids to both the pending Intent and getting a common broadcast for both the actions.

Change the ID in the following line to 1
PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
            switchIntent, 0);

Like this
PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, 
            switchIntent, 0);

It should work fine now!